# Compile time error while building Linux Kernel 4.18

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, linux-kernel

I am trying to disable inlining while compiling Linux kernel 4.18.

For this I have updated the Makefile according to: https://elinux.org/Kernel_dynamic_memory_analysis#Obtaining_accurate_call_sites_.28or_The_painstaking_task_of_wrestling_against_gcc.29

But while compiling I am getting following error:

> error: call to ‘__compiletime_assert_1094’ declared with attribute error: BUILD_BUG_ON failed: p4d_large(*p4d)

How can I get rid of the error while disabling inlining during kernel build?

Answer (score 0):

`BUILD_BUG_ON()` requires a constant expression. Sometimes calls to inline functions are passed to it. GCC is capable of optimizing some inline functions to constant expressions, making it work. Disabling inlining will prevent this, breaking the build. (In some cases this is also a problem for Clang, which does semantic analysis before inlining.)

You'd probably have to change quite a bit of code to be able to build the kernel with inlining disabled. The page you refer to is fairly old; presumably this was not a problem back then.